# reader.onload callback issue with typescript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-upload

I am building a simple file upload using angular2. 
i have the following code. In the code the callback is assigned to onload. After that the context changes to reader and not the class in which it is present. I can't access other objects in overview class

```
    export class overview {
       change() {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = this.uploadFile;
          reader.readAsDataURL($("input[name='image']")[0].files[0]);
        }
       uploadFile() {
        console.log(this); //"this" refers to reader obj,how can i get the overview object
       this.api('upload'); //this does not work because api is undefined
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword this takes a new context based on it's caller. You can override this default behaviur with a constructor for your class and explicitly bind the context of this for all your methods.

```
constructor() {
    for (var name in this) {
        if ($.isFunction(this[name])) {
            this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This function loops through all the properties of the class, and uses jQuery to check if the property is a method. It then binds the context of this to be always the class level. Note this won't have any effect on anonymous functions, in which case you can use a variable to keep track of this. Such as

```
public Test(): void {
    var self = this;
    something.callback = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(self); //will be your class level
    }
}
```